# Phpmyadmin Importing sql file error "... for the right syntax to use near '1'"

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I used phpmyadmin in xampp to import a sql file to generate a database for a tutorial course, and got this error:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1'".

Database server:
Server version: 10.4.13-MariaDB

I searched this forum, it seems that there is a lot of similar questions, but there is no solution that can fix my problem.

My questions:

1. What does "near '1'" mean? What is wrong with line 8?
2. Is there a way to fix the whole sql file for importing without errors? (I can provide the sql file if anyone is available to help. By the way, I don't know how to attach the sql file here.)

Here is the portion of sql file that the errors points to:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=764 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci COMMENT='帖子评论的互动数据表，记录了一条评论的点赞，分享，评论的数量';
CREATE TABLE `table_feeds_comment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment_text` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
  `comment_type` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `create_time` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_url` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `like_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `video_url` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `width` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

[image: Here is the screenshot in phpmyadmin]

Comment: The error continues on the next line, the problem occurs with the `'1'` part of the `comment_type` line, but to provide enough context to show you that part MySQL quotes the next two lines. That all being said, I was able to import that segment of code without trouble in MariaDB using phpMyAdmin. It could be what Yim Johns suggested, otherwise I'd suggest looking at whether your server is running in a compatibility mode or some other unusual configuration.

Comment: Do you have any triggers?

Comment: Your file loads fine without any problem in to my MySQL 8.0.18. MariaDB 10.4.8 and 10.4.13 give an error `Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'` but if I change those to another collation it imports fine. The errors you're seeing aren't from phpMyAdmin directly, they're something MySQL/MariaDB returns that is shown by phpMyAdmin, so my best guess is that something isn't quite right with your server, but I'm not sure what. I am surprised that you don't get the collation error with MariaDB, though; even though it's not really related it seems strange. To be honest, I'm running low on ideas.

Comment: Thanks, Isaac. Yes, I got erro with "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", and I changed it to "utf8mb4_general_ci". Is my MYSQL version low?

Comment: I tested with the same version you report having, MariaDB 10.4.13, so your problem doesn't seem to be related to the particular version. I think the collation is one of the (very few noticeable) differences between MySQL and MariaDB.

Comment: Thanks, Isaac. So, any idea about why I got the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while I worked with PHP though but here's my submission below:

comment_type int(11) DEFAULT '1'

You specified comment_type as an integer type but you supplied a DEFAULT that is of a char type.
You may need to change it to 1 without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the following part of the sql file which is at the beginning, and imported it successfully. But I still don't know why these syntaxes have created the problem. Are these syntaxes not compatible with my MYSQL version? In what version of MYSQL are these syntaxes are used?

```
/*
MySQL Backup
Database: serverdemo
Backup Time: 2019-11-29 14:10:46
*/

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `serverdemo`.`hibernate_sequence`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `serverdemo`.`table_feed_comment_like`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `serverdemo`.`table_feed_comment_ugc`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `serverdemo`.`table_feeds_comment`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `serverdemo`.`table_hot_feeds`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `serverdemo`.`table_tag_list`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `serverdemo`.`table_tag_list_like`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `serverdemo`.`table_ugc`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `serverdemo`.`table_ugc_like`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `serverdemo`.`table_user`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `serverdemo`.`table_user_banner`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `serverdemo`.`table_user_follow`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `serverdemo`.`table_watch_history`;
```

Comment: None of this should cause the error you're seeing, unless there's some other oddity that cascaded down the line. This is quite strange, except for disabling the foreign key checks, the rest of this just deletes the old tables if they already existed, and the foreign key line should not matter for creating a table. You might have to post the entire SQL file if you want further help debugging it.

Comment: Here is the sql file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1o1ugylsmiesmhx/test.sql?dl=0